# Kubernetes NGINX Ingress Controller not picking up TLS Certificates

Tags: ssl, nginx, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I setup a new kubernetes cluster on GKE using the [nginx-ingress](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx) controller. TLS is not working, it's using the fake certificates.

There is a lot of configuration detail so I made a repo - https://github.com/jobevers/test_ssl_ingress

In short the steps were

- create a new cluster without GKE's load balancer
- create a tls secret with my key and cert
- create an nginx-ingress deployment / pod
- create an ingress controller

The nginx-ingress config comes from https://zihao.me/post/cheap-out-google-container-engine-load-balancer/ (and looks very similar to a lot of the examples in the ingress-nginx repo).

My ingress.yaml is nearly identical to [the example one](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/examples/tls-termination/nginx/nginx-tls-ingress.yaml)

When I run curl, I get

```
$ curl -kv https://35.196.134.52
[...]
*    common name: Kubernetes Ingress Controller Fake Certificate (does not match '35.196.134.52')
[...]
*    issuer: O=Acme Co,CN=Kubernetes Ingress Controller Fake Certificate
[...]
```

which shows that I'm still using the default certificates.

How am I supposed to get it using mine?

---

[Ingress definition](https://github.com/jobevers/test_ssl_ingress/blob/master/ingress.yaml)

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ssl-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  tls:
    - secretName: tls-secret
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: demo-echo-service
          servicePort: 80
```

---

[Creating the secret](https://github.com/jobevers/test_ssl_ingress/blob/master/setup_cluster_with_ssl.sh#L22):

```
kubectl create secret tls tls-secret --key tls/privkey.pem --cert tls/fullchain.pem
```

---

Debugging further, the certificate is being found and exist on the server:

```
$ kubectl -n kube-system exec -it $(kubectl -n kube-system get pods | grep ingress | head -1 | cut -f 1 -d " ") -- ls -1 /ingress-controller/ssl/
default-fake-certificate-full-chain.pem
default-fake-certificate.pem
default-tls-secret-full-chain.pem
default-tls-secret.pem
```

And, from the log, I see

```
kubectl -n kube-system log -f $(kubectl -n kube-system get pods | grep ingress | head -1 | cut -f 1 -d " ")
[...]
I1013 17:21:45.423998       6 queue.go:111] syncing default/test-ssl-ingress
I1013 17:21:45.424009       6 backend_ssl.go:40] starting syncing of secret default/tls-secret
I1013 17:21:45.424135       6 ssl.go:60] Creating temp file /ingress-controller/ssl/default-tls-secret.pem236555242 for Keypair: default-tls-secret.pem
I1013 17:21:45.424946       6 ssl.go:118] parsing ssl certificate extensions
I1013 17:21:45.743635       6 backend_ssl.go:102] found 'tls.crt' and 'tls.key', configuring default/tls-secret as a TLS Secret (CN: [...])
[...]
```

But, looking at the nginx.conf, its still using the fake certs:

```
$ kubectl -n kube-system exec -it $(kubectl -n kube-system get pods | grep ingress | head -1 | cut -f 1 -d " ") -- cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf | grep ssl_cert
        ssl_certificate                         /ingress-controller/ssl/default-fake-certificate.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key                     /ingress-controller/ssl/default-fake-certificate.pem;
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Turns out that the ingress definition needs to look like:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ssl-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - app.example.com
      secretName: tls-secret
  rules:
    - host: app.example.com
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /
          backend:
            serviceName: demo-echo-service
            servicePort: 80
```

The host entry under rules needs to match one of the hosts entries under tls.

Comment: Thanks for putting it plainly. I've been having an issue with my cluster since it needs to serve wildcard domains over HTTPS and any arbitrary domain pointed at it over HTTP. Just duplicating one of the rules and explicitly adding the wildcard domain completely sorted it for me.

Comment: For me it was the ingress class that wasn't correct.

Comment: How should this configuration look for a wildcard certificate and domain?

Comment: Thanks for providing this config explicitly. As for me, I added `hosts` for `tls` section, but skipped it (for some reason) for `rules` section. After duplicating host name in `rules`, it started to work propertly

Comment: This is not working for me.  How do I debug EXACTLY what the system is doing so I can find out why it is being an insolent piece of crud?

Comment: Just to piggyback on this answer if anyone else comes across it, @jobevers debugging lines helped my find that when I used openssl to create the PEM files from our PFX file, I had a bunch of random stuff at the top of the file, and the error in NGINX logs showed that the pem files need to start with -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- worth having a look at the PEM files and making sure they are 'clean'. Manually deleting the guff at the top and recreating the secret worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just faced that issue as well with `v0.30.0` and it turns out that having an ingress config like this without explicit hostnames is ok:

```
spec:
  tls:
    - secretName: ssl-certificate
```

On my side the problem was that I had a annotation on the ingress with an `int64` value that was not parsed correctly and below that was the definiton `kubernetes.io/ingress.class` so essentially nginx did not find the ingress controller which was stated in the logs correctly:

```
ignoring add for ingress <ingressname> based on annotation kubernetes.io/ingress.class with value
```

So using strings in the annotations fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found that to use wild host tls we need to have tls host name and rules host name both using wild card for example:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ssl-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - "*.example.com"
      secretName: tls-secret
  rules:
    - host: "*.example.com"
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /
          backend:
            serviceName: demo-echo-service
            servicePort: 80
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to add the ROOT CA Certificate to authorities section in places such as chrome, firefox, the server's certificate pool.

1. Create a directory called **/usr/share/ca-certificates/extras**
2. Change extension of **.pem** file to **.crt** and copy this file to
   directory you created
3. Run **sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates**
4. In window that opens, first press enter, then select the file you
   added in list that appears with space key and press enter again

Your computer will now automatically recognize other certificates, you have generated with this certificate.